# Racket bad syntax error when #<eof> in a list

Tags: racket, eof

I have some code that reads in a file and turns it into a list of characters

```
(define in (open-input-file "some-file.txt"))

(define (file->char-list inp)
  ;; convert the input file into a list of chars
  (let ([content (read-char inp)])
    (if (eof-object? content)
    (list eof)
    (cons content (file->char-list inp)))))

(define char-list (file->char-list in)

(println char-list)

 read-syntax: bad syntax `#<`
'(#\s #\o #\m #\e #\space #\t #\e #\x #\t #<eof>)
```

But the issue is that the eof in the file gives a bad syntax error. I need the eof to be in the list because I plan on doing something with it, but I'm surprised I'm getting the error because the values are quoted and when I evaluate `eof` in the repl I also get #. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: The code you pasted above works for me. Are you doing anything else with the result that could be generating the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no end-of-file character in files on typical modern operating systems. Instead, the operating system signals when end-of-file is reached by some file I/O operation. In order for this signalling to be effective, a unique value must be returned to the caller of the I/O operation which can be distinguished from any valid data that might be received. In the case of Racket, this value is [`eof`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html?q=eof#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eof%29%29), which is a distinct value that represents end-of-file.

The `eof` object is printed as an [unreadable value](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html?q=unreadable%20object#%28part._print-unreadable%29); you don't want the reader encountering end-of-file in the middle of a program. When you enter `eof` at the REPL, the symbol `'eof` evaluates to the end-of-file object, which will usually be printed as an unreadable value with `#<eof>`. If you try to give `#<eof>` to the reader, say by including it in a quoted list with `'(#\s #\o #\m #\e #\space #\t #\e #\x #\t #<eof>)`, the reader will complain. This is as it should be.

I can't think of any reason the OP should need to work with the `eof` object that has been returned when end-of-file is reached. OP could just as well do something like:

```
(define (file->char-list inp)
  ;; convert the input file into a list of chars
  (let ([content (read-char inp)])
    (if (eof-object? content)
        '()
        (cons content (file->char-list inp)))))
```

When working with the list created by:

```
(define char-list (file->char-list in))
char-list  ==>  '(#\s #\o #\m #\e #\space #\t #\e #\x #\t)
```

it is known that end-of-file was reached when the end of the list is reached. If OP wants to "transform" the `eof` in some way, a new character could simply be appended to the end of the list.

Comment: I'm experimenting with tokenizing html elements for a project that I'm working on. In the html spec eofs are handled differently depending on which state the lexer is in when an eof is encountered. I've never worked with unreadable values before. In every case up until this I've never had to deal with them. But now that I know that #<eof> is not a value I can work with directly, I will use '() as a proxy. I appreciate the explanation!